# How to add User to Role using ASP.NET Core Identity framework services In multi-tenancy architecture

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

We are implementing Multi-tenant architecture for our project.

1. I have created User using `userManager.CreateAsync(user, register.Password);`
2. Then Created Admin role using `await roleManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole("Admin", ParentCompanyId))`
3. Then I am trying to add "Admin" role to created User using `userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleAdmin);`

since our application is for multiple tenant and having Tenant wise Admin role in `AspNetRoles` table so `AddToRoleAsync()` is failing caz its not getting correct Admin role or having ambigious "Admin" role in `AspNetRoles` table so throwing below exception. so can anyone guide me please how to add correct role to particular user. Since identity framework don't have any service to assign Role to user using `RoleID`, it would have been simpler. Can anyone give solution for this approach or can suggest correct approach to add user to roles.

How to add User to Role using asp.net core Identity Framework services In Multi tenancy Architecture. I am not able to add user to Admin role tenantwise using `userManager.AddToRoleAsync()`,

Receiving Below Exception on executing `userManager.AddToRoleAsync(User,Role)` method

> "System.InvalidOperationException: Enumerator failed to MoveNextAsync.
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1
> asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1
> asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.IsInRoleAsync(TUser
> user, String normalizedRoleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.AddToRoleAsync(TUser
> user, String role)    at
> Salon.Controllers.AccountController.SignUp(RegisterViewModel register)
> in C:\Users\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 78"

Comment: What have you tried? As codes I mean

Comment: @Mayk : i have updated my question in detail

Comment: So each role is connected to a tenant, correct? So you can have multiple Admin roles that are form different tenants? And how are you resolving the tenants?

Answer (score 4):

The way to do is to overwrite the default RoleStore and filter the roles by tenant in the custom RoleStore.

For this solution i'm assuming you are using SaasKit to resolve your tenants and your custom IdentityRole has a Tenant property.

If you look at the [source code of UserManager.AddToRoleAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f8da3e2e331833ff23f8f4ad6ab45c900a362f4b/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1207) they just use the provided RoleStore.

So if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f8da3e2e331833ff23f8f4ad6ab45c900a362f4b/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/RoleStore.cs#L433) of the RoleStore, you can see all queries are done via Roles property. By adding a filter of tenants there you can always get the relevant Role assuming the tenant is resolved.

So the custom RoleStore:

```
public class TenantRoleStore : RoleStore<ApplicationRole<string>>
{
    private readonly TenantContext<Tenant> _tenantContext;

    public TenantRoleStore(
        CustomDbContext context,
        TenantContext<Tenant> tenantContext,
        IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null)
        : base(context, describer)
    {
        _tenantContext = tenantContext;
    }

    public override IQueryable<ApplicationRole<string>> Roles => base.Roles.Where(r => r.Tenant.Id == _tenantContext.Tenant.Id);
}
```

In the startup just add it where you configure Identity:

```
services.AddIdentity()
    .AddRoleStore<TenantRoleStore>(); // <- add this
```

Comment: but by ApplicationRole inheret from  IdentityRole<Guid> also  I use dotnet 6 how can i fix this

Comment: @TariqHajeer what do you have so far? What issue are you running in to?

Comment: I solve  it by adding TenantUserStore class inherit from UserStore<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole,ApplicationDbContext,Guid> 
this work with me

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried the query you mentioned above. Then I inspected the sql query, it does not have tenant filter. Very weird. Csn you help me please